# How do I remove the objects when it is not seen on the camera?

Tags: c#, camera, platformer, frustum-culling

I am a beginner C# Developer and I am creating my own version of the "No Internet Dinosaur Game." 
How do I remove the Object like (Platforms, Cactus, etc.) When it is not seen on the camera?

[image]

Comment: You've tagged this "frustum culling" which is *hiding* objects not seen by the camera. Unity already does this for you. If you want to destroy/recycle those objects, presumably you considered using OnBecameInvisible or triggers to run your reclamation routine?

Comment: How do you do that kind of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials about infinite procedural generation. Usually they all have the behaviour of cleaning up objects that are left behind the player, and creating objects in front of the player when required. It can be done in multiple ways.

If you just want to know if the object is off screen or not, this question may help: [Identify whether object is off screen or not](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132894/identify-whether-object-is-off-screen-or-not/132955#132955)

Simply put, easiest way: you keep track of all generated objects, generate a certain quantiy of platforms right away, so that they cover visibility from both sides. Keep track of point where player has been last time something was generated, when player moves some distance away from this last point = generate a new platform and delete platform from behind, usually it will be at 0 index in the list of all generated objects.

[Infinite Runner in Unity - PLATFORM GENERATOR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYD9iq8ku_w)

Actually there are too many approaches, so: [Youtube Search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=unity%20infinite%20platformer)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this script on the object you want to get destroyed as soon as it leaves view:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyWhenInvisible: MonoBehaviour {
    void OnBecameInvisible() {
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

However, in many cases this will go a bit too far. There might be situations where an object becomes invisible for another reason than leaving the play area, for example when you start to implement fancier camera controls. So it can be useful to solve this with a different approach.

A common approach is to create a kind of "cleanup zone". A collider with "Is Trigger" enabled which is just outside of the play area and destroys any object that enters it. Here is an example script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CleanupArea: MonoBehaviour {
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
         Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

When the cleanup area ends up not cleaning up things it should or cleans up things it shouldn't clean up, then there are various reasons why this could happen. Check the Unity manual article on [colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html), on [layer-based collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) for more information on how to correctly use trigger areas.